# How to get rid of 'object is possibly undefined' in array function?

Tags: typescript

In the code below I get a ts error that `output` is possibly undefined. How can I get rid of that error and get on with my coding? I would have thought that since I short circuit the evaluation using `&&` prior to accessing a property on `undefined` I wouldn't get a type error.

```
const outputs = stack.Outputs;
if (!outputs) {
  throw new Error(`Unable to get stack output. Stack ${stackName} has no outputs.`)
}

const output = outputs.find(output => output && output.OutputKey === outputKey)
```

[image]

Comment: Is it saying that the whole expression is possibly undefined?  It is, null, possibly. `output` is guarded starting at the second half of the conjunction.

Comment: @danh: I clarified the question

Comment: Can this be put into a playground so we can play around with it ourselves?

Comment: If I didn't understand that the throw halts execution, I'd see a path to outputs being undefined, too.  Maybe that's what's happening to the ts check.  Two ideas: (1) do the find in an `else` block, (2) guard with a conditional chain, like `outputs?.find(...`

Answer (score 0):

set a conditional to only perform the find method if it's not undefined.

Example:

```
if(output) {
outputs.find(output => output && output.OutputKey === outputKey)
}
```